# How to solve nodejs puppeteer Cannot find module 'puppeteer' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have installed puppeteer

`

```
const automation = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");
const automationConfiguration = {
    headless: false
    }

    async function runautomation() {


const browser = await automation.launch(automationConfiguration)

const page = await browser.newPage()
const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation()

await navigationPromise

await page.goto('https://www.google.com/search?q=perfmatters+vs+wp+rocket&oq=perf&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0i67j46i433i512j0i433i512l2j0i131i433i512j69i64.961j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8')

await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 657 })

await page.waitForSelector('.MjjYud:nth-child(5) > .g > .kvH3mc > .Z26q7c > .yuRUbf > a > .LC20lb')
await page.click('.MjjYud:nth-child(5) > .g > .kvH3mc > .Z26q7c > .yuRUbf > a > .LC20lb')

await navigationPromise

await browser.close() }
runautomation()
```

`

I have tried everyting from my end but nothing works im new to puppeteer please help

Comment: Have you tried adding executionPath to browser configaration? And you'll also probably need to install chrome driver or geckodriver on local machine depending on browser you want to use

Comment: How did you install puppeteer exactly? (commands, package.json, OS)

Comment: I have installed puppeteer with this command: npm install puppeteer.

Comment: my other puppeteer code is working but this one is not,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have solved the issue i installed the puppeteer on different folder i dont know that i need to install puppeteer on every project